# create 2 different endpoints in azure APIM for same function app

Tags: azure-api-management

**I have single azure function app. I want to create 2 different API endpoints in Azure APIM. How I can do that?**

Comment: You can create one API with two operations. Each operation calls the Function App

Comment: I tried with adding operation but it is not pointing to same function app. I am getting status 404 Resource not found with another Operation

Answer (score 1):

According to some test, it seems we can't implement the requirement by adding an operation in api management because it will show error message `Operation with the same method and URL template already exists`.
[image]

And if we use some other methods such as clone the operation, it will also fail with 404 error because the `URL` field will change and can not match the function url.

So I think you can just add another api in your api management to implement the requirement (shown like below screenshot).
[image]

The two APIM endpoints should be:
`https://huryapim.azure-api.net/huryFun1/HttpTrigger1` and `https://huryapim.azure-api.net/huryFun2/HttpTrigger1`. Both of them request the same azure function url in backend.

Comment: Its not ideal, but it works. Hopefully Azure team can make it better...