# Does it possible to save WebSocket gateway with the same route in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

We are using Azure API Management where is supporting WebSocket, but we need 2 different endpoint routes for it, because you can`t create route to your API:
`http(s)://{base_url}` and `ws(s)://{base_url}`,
you must add difference by using suffix, like :

```
http(s)://{base_url}
ws(s)://{base_url}/{suffix}
```

or

```
http(s)://{base_url}/{suffix}
ws(s)://{base_url}
```

How we can configure same endpoits ?

Comment: Using socket.io and facing the same problem. Have you ever found any workaround? @omnomnom ?

Answer (score 0):

During the WebSocket passthrough the client application establishes a WebSocket connection with the API Management Gateway

Check for the steps in adding WebSocket API to APIM [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api#add-a-websocket-api).

Make sure we follow below limitations:

- WebSocket APIs are not supported yet in the Consumption tier.
- WebSocket APIs are not supported yet in the  [self-hosted gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview).
- Azure CLI, PowerShell, and SDK currently do not support management operations of WebSocket APIs

Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64207051/create-2-different-endpoints-in-azure-apim-for-same-function-app) thread in including two endpoints for same URL in backend, thanks to Hury for great explanation. Though it is for functions app, but the process is similar.